# dot product of two numpy arrays with known dimensions does not come out with the expected dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dimensions

I'm dot product-ting 2 numpy arrays, one with dimensions (150, 4), the other with (4, 1). This should result in an array with dimensions (150, 1), however, I'm getting an array of (150, 4).

I've tried creating a list of lists of the data and passing that into the array constructor.

```
x = iris.data #shape (150, 4)
y = np.array(y_actual) #shape (150, 1)

np.random.seed(1)

syn1 = 2 * np.random.random( (x.shape[1], x.shape[1]) ) - 1
syn2 = 2 * np.random.random( (x.shape[1], y.shape[1]) ) - 1

for i in range(10000):
    layer0 = x
    layer1 = sigmoid( np.dot(layer0, syn1) )
    layer2 = sigmoid( np.dot(layer1, syn2) )

    l2_err = layer2 - y

    l2_delta = l2_err * sigmoid(layer2, deriv = True)
    l1_err = np.dot(l2_delta, syn2.T)
    l1_delta = l1_err * sigmoid(layer1, deriv = True)
```

I expect the dimensions of layer2 to be (150, 1), but I'm receiving dimensions of (150, 4).

Answer (score 0):

I've added dimensions - as best I can deduce:

```
x = iris.data #shape (150, 4)
y = np.array(y_actual) #shape (150, 1)

np.random.seed(1)

syn1 = 2 * np.random.random( (x.shape[1], x.shape[1]) ) - 1  # (4,4)
syn2 = 2 * np.random.random( (x.shape[1], y.shape[1]) ) - 1  # (4,1)

for i in range(10000):
    layer0 = x
    layer1 = sigmoid( np.dot(layer0, syn1) )   # (150,4) dot (4,4)=>(150,4)
    layer2 = sigmoid( np.dot(layer1, syn2) )   # (150,4) dot (4,1)=>(150,1)

    l2_err = layer2 - y       # (150,1) (150,1) => (150,1)

    l2_delta = l2_err * sigmoid(layer2, deriv = True)
    l1_err = np.dot(l2_delta, syn2.T)     # (150,1) (1,4) => (150,4)
    l1_delta = l1_err * sigmoid(layer1, deriv = True)
```

Comment: yes, layer2 should be a (150, 1) array, but after that computation is done, layer2 somehow ends up as a (150, 4) array. Is there a reason this should occur?